# How to create Qt custom base class

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, moc

I would like to create a custom `main window` for my application and I would like to integrate it with `Qt Creator`. When you create a new `Qt Widgets Application` you get the option of inheriting from `QWidget`, `QMainWindow` or `QDialog`. I would like to add my own widget there:

[image]

I would like my custom `.ui` form to be generated when I select my custom widget from the drop down list. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Or maybe it is possible to add a custom template widget to the `Qt Designer Form` dialog when creating a new form? I'm talking about this:

[image]

Regards!

Comment: just replace the QMainWindow references in the header file

Comment: @ratchetfreak But AFAIK this change doesn't reflect in the `.ui` form. I would like to have the `.ui` form to visually resemble my widget in the `Qt Designer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate a custom widget with Qt Designer, you require a suitable description for the widget and an appropriate .pro file.
It is documented here:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html

Comment: Does this also provide means to create custom widget templates? e.g. when you create a new form I'd like to be able to choose that custom widget

Comment: It doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: What do you mean by `It doesn't look like it to me`?

Comment: I successfully created qt designer plug-ins and integrated them with qt designer but my goal is to create template forms(forms that appear under `templates\forms` or under `Widgets` in the second screenshot above). Is this possible?

Comment: These templates were introduced with Qt 4.8 and since then somewhat forgotten. I don't know if a system exists to add custom ones as a user. However on a linux system, you find the file /usr/share/qtcreator/designer/templates.xml that contains these templates. You can add other .ui files in the XML. On other systems, check the appropriate installation paths.

Comment: I tried adding my templates to `/usr/share/qtcreator/designer/templates.xml` and to `/usr/share/qtcreator/designer/templates` but unfortunately it doesn't work. Do you know any other place things could be changed in order to add new templates?

Comment: No, that's all I know, but I don't see why it should not work if there is no error somewhere.